# How to make a new instance of a struct in c

Tags: c, struct, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am new to C and thus still working on learning the language. I have created a linked list struct in a header file and I am trying to create a new instance of this struct. I know in java you can use the `new` operator but how would I mimic this behavior in c? Traditionally I would think of the following:

code within linked.h

```
typedef struct linked_list{
//assuming node type is implemented
node *next_node; 
}
```

code within linked.c

```
linked_list *link = NULL;
link = malloc(number_nodes);
link->node_value = 10;
```

Any help you can provide is extremely helpful to me as I am having trouble understanding this concept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`malloc` needs to know how many *bytes* to allocate, so you need to multiply the number of nodes by the size of one node in bytes.

Change:

```
link = malloc(number_nodes);
```

to

```
link = malloc(number_nodes * sizeof(*link));
```

Or if you just want a single struct:

```
link = malloc(sizeof(*link));
```

Comment: Thank you, but this will provide me with an actual instance?

Comment: That will give you `number_nodes` instances of `linked_list`, which may or may not be what you actually want.

Comment: Oh no, I just want one instance to work with. One linked list, I was under the impression I would have to allocate as much memory as I would be using with the linked list. Thus I passed the number of nodes to malloc

Comment: Well the code fragments you have posted are somewhat muddled, so it's hard to guess what your actual intent is. You might want to study some linked list code in a good book on C to get a better overall understanding of what you need to be doing.

Comment: okay, so if I just wanted to allocate enough memory for one instance of a linked list, with an unknown amount of nodes. How would I do this?

Comment: Mind that  `number_nodes * sizeof(*link)` can overflow for a big value of number_nodes. If this is user supplied be careful to add safety checks. (while even without overflow taking that from users is questionable as they might allocate lots of memory)

Comment: Mind as well that each node should be allocated individually. So the last line of this answer is the correct one. You could as well do otherwise, but then you'd have to maintain a list of used and unused nodes in the `malloc()`'ed block, and it will become a PITA.

Answer (score 2):

If you want enough memory for one `struct linked_list`, all you have to do is

```
struct linked_list * mylist = malloc(sizeof(*mylist));
mylist -> next_node = NULL;
```

For each node you want to add, you have to do

```
struct node * mynewnode = malloc(sizeof(*mynewnode));
mynewnode -> ... = ...; // fill in the data you have
mynewnode -> next_node = mylist -> next_node;
mylist -> next_node = mynewnode;
```

You should maintain the memory of all nodes independent on each other so you can free them.